# What does an expression consisting of comma-separated variables inside curly braces mean? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to decipher some code and I stumbled upon this:

```js
var disabled = mswDisabledValue === 'true' ? true : false;
var serviceWorkers = JSON.parse("[{\"scope\":\"/\",\"serviceWorkerUrl\":\"/uxsw/scope/root.js\"},{\"scope\":\"/x\",\"serviceWorkerUrl\":\"/uxsw/scope/now_x.js\"},{\"scope\":\"/now\",\"serviceWorkerUrl\":\"/uxsw/scope/now_x.js\"}]");
var SERVICE_WORKER_MANAGER_CONFIG = { disabled, serviceWorkers };
```

What does the third line mean?

I tried printing `SERVICE_WORKER_MANAGER_CONFIG`, and it returned an object:

```
{
  disabled: false,
  serviceWorkers: [{
      scope: '/',
      serviceWorkerUrl: '/uxsw/scope/root.js'
    },
    {
      scope: '/x',
      serviceWorkerUrl: '/uxsw/scope/now_x.js'
    },
    {
      scope: '/now',
      serviceWorkerUrl: '/uxsw/scope/now_x.js'
    }
  ]
}
```

Seems like I can declare an object using variables instead of key/value pairs, but I haven't found this documented anywhere. Is this the correct usage of JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, this is valid javascript. It's a shorthand for `{ disabled: disabled, serviceWorkers: serviceWorkers }`. Saves you some keystrokes.

Comment: While you're learning from this code, note that the **first** line should be `var disabled = mswDisabledValue === 'true';` — the `? :` operator is completely unnecessary there, because the `===` comparison will result in `true` or `false`.

Comment: It is described in the JavaScript documentation of [object initializers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
var SERVICE_WORKER_MANAGER_CONFIG = {disabled, serviceWorkers};
```

is a valid javascript object initializer. It is also called "Object literal syntax" and it is used as a shorthand for initializing JSON objects. It is identical to calling:

```
var SERVICE_WORKER_MANAGER_CONFIG = {disabled : disabled, serviceWorkers : serviceWorkers};
```

More information and examples can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#object_literal_syntax_vs._json).